# Smell coming from the bottom of the wall

Tags: drywall, flooring

We just bought a house and they renovated some of it and installed laminate flooring.
I noticed a bad smell coming from a bottom corner of a room.
It is pretty hard to describe, I would say its mold but im not sure. It kinda smells old and musty and it's only in that one corner.

I got one of those small camera and checked the inside of the wall. It is pretty hard to see anything with all the insulation but it looked fine I think.
Is there anything else I could try to do to check the source of that smell and make sure its not something bad?

Thank you!

Comment: A moisture meter and an IR camera might help identify a moisture problem non-destructively.

Comment: Is this room on the ground floor or basement? Any plumbing nearby such as a bathroom?

Comment: Its on a slab. No plumbing but its against the outside wall.

Comment: Dead mouse? If so, it'll eventually dry out and stop stinking.

Answer (score 1):

You've done the easy stuff, now it's time for a more advanced approach. You should think about removing the drywall in that corner and investigate further. See if the drywall on the opposite side of the corner will be easier to fix. Musty smells are a sign of recent moisture so you need to check this out.